# What is the gradle dependency for cucumber.api.Scenario

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, build.gradle, gherkin

Currently I am working in a project with BDD it involves some importing statement like

import cucumber.api.Scenario;

But i am not able to find the right dependency for it

Currently I am having dependencies like

```
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.3'
compile'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.44.0'
compile group:'org.seleniumhq.selenium',name:'selenium-java',version:'3.4.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'
compile group: 'org.codehaus.plexus', name: 'plexus-utils', version: '1.1'
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion"
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:$httpcomponentsVersion"
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:$httpcomponentsVersion"
compile "com.aventstack:extentreports:$extentreportVersion"
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '2.0.0'
testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '5.4.0'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-testng', version: '5.4.0'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '5.4.0'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: '5.4.0'
```

Comment: `'cucumber-java', version: '2.0.0'` that doesn't look right.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a mistake. Furthermore, there should be only one of `cucumber-java` and `cucumber-java8` - not both. Same with junit and testng. There is also some mixup with `compile` and `testCompile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cucumber.api.Scenario` class is for Cucumber 4 but you are depending on Cucumber 5. In this newer version, the packages were relocated to `io.cucumber`.

So if you have an existing Cucumber project written for version 4, you need to change your dependencies from `5.4.0` to one in the version 4 range. The latest is `4.8.1`.

If it is a new project, it is probably better to go with the newer version, but of cause you will need to learn how to work with it. The main changes to the previous version are listed in the [release notes for 5.0.0](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/release-notes/v5.0.0.md)